# change value of ng-repeat item on click

Tags: angularjs

```
<table class="table table-mailbox">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in inboxItems | filter : search" 
     class="{{item.read == 'true' ? 'read' : 'unread'}}" >
  <td class="small-col"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  <td class="small-col"><i ng-click="item.starred = !item.starred" class="{{item.starred == 'true' ? 'fa fa-star' : 'fa fa-star-o'}}"></i></td>
  <td class="name"><a href="#">{{item.from}}</a></td>
  <td class="subject"><a href="#">{{item.subject}}</a></td>
  <td class="time">{{item.time}}</td>
  </tr>                                    
</table>
```

in the above code, i'm trying to change the value of item.starred from true to false, or vice versa on click. But when it changes from false to true, 'fa fa-star-o' class is not assigned.

I am new to angularjs, please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the ngClass directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) instead.

```
<td class="small-col"><i ng-click="item.starred = !item.starred" ng-class="item.starred ? 'fa fa-star' : 'fa fa-star-o'"></i></td>
```

Comment: i'm able to toggle b/w classes now, but it always selects 'fa fa-star', even if item.starred is false.

Comment: Are you sure it's false? Maybe this plunker will help: http://plnkr.co/edit/yPuS5dGINVxmUEE9GuiH?p=preview

Comment: Yes. For some items its false by default. but still its going into the true condition.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the string 'false'? The reason I ask is in your question you're doing a string comparison. If you click it twice what happens?

Comment: I changed it from string to boolean. Works fine now. Thanx Andy